# Перенаправление GET

Tags: php

```
INDEX.php
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=TEST.php?rstatus=test\">";
INDEX;

TEST.php
$rstatus = $_GET['rstatus'];
TEST;
```

Почему когда я попадаю на страницу куда перенаправляю я не получаю значение GET??

Comment: а использование META=refresh - это обязательное условие?.. джаваскриптом много легче перенаправить с гетом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем писать HTML

```
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=TEST.php?rstatus=test\">";
```

если есть header в php

```
 header("Location: index.php?rstatus=test");
```

Answer (score 4):

*Здравствуйте.*

Зачем Вы внедряете **html** код с перенаправлением?

Все это можно легко сделать *НЕ* используя данный метод:

на **php:**

```
header("Location: index.php?rstatus=test");
```

на **JavaScript:**

```
<script>location.href='index.php?rstatus=test';</script>
```

Аналогично, **JavaScript** Уже можно выводить через **php:**

```
echo "<script>location.href='index.php?rstatus=test';</script>";
```

Так будет более проще и правильнее.

Comment: а где у вас вывод-то переменной ?